# Is it a Philodendron "Imperial Red" or a "Rojo Congo"? How to tell these two varieties apart?

Tags: identification, houseplants, aroid, philodendron

I came across this plant at a local nursery and it was labelled as *Philodendron*. Without any species or variety information.

Now I am almost sure that it is not a "Black Cardinal". I think it is either an "Imperial Red" or a "Rojo Congo" but at this point I cannot decide. Even after checking countless images of both.

Here are some pictures of the leaves, stem and the whole plant. For reference the pot was a 21 cm one, so the plant was quite large.

| [image] | [image] |
| --- | --- |
| [image] | [image] |

[image]